# How to stop Django from rendering result in new tab

Tags: django

I have following views and each time form is submitted, result is rendered in new tab which has empty form.

How to render result in same form (with data submitted) without opening new tab?

views.py

```
class contact(View):
    def __init__(self, logger=None, **kwargs):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        
    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'test.html')
   
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                self.host = form.data['ip']
                messages.success(request, "Successful")
                
            else:
                form = ContactForm()
    
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
            
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    ip = forms.CharField()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', contact.as_view()),
]
```

html

```
<body>
    <form action="/" method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you aware of `ajax`

Comment: I'm now. I don't want to use java.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid()

     form.save()
     messages.success(request, 'Contact request submitted successfully.')
     return render(request, 'your_page.html', {'form': ContactForm(request.GET)})
```

Comment: Thanks. It's still opening new tab as soon as I click submit. I'm not using models.

Comment: Thanks. I had  "target="_blank"" in my form which I missed to post here. After removing it, results are rendered in the same page.